# Set direction sheet in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I trying to export my database data to excel file, so I use PHPExcel classes.

my sheet should be Right to left, How can I switch sheet direction to 'RTL' in PHPExcel ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quoting directly from the developer documentation, which can be found in the /Documentation folder of the distribution:

> **4.6.48. Right-to-left worksheet**
>
> Worksheets can be set individually whether column ‘A’ should start at left or right side. Default is left. Here is how to set columns from right-to-left.

```
// right-to-left worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setRightToLeft(true);
```