# PHP Excel - Set cell or Column Direction (RTL)

Tags: php, cell, phpexcel, right-to-left

I'm looking for a way to set the "Direction" of a cell in Excel from PHP Excel.
I've gone over any documentation i could find and found only the option to set the direction for a sheet, however, it does not affect the cell direction but rather, only the layout of the page from LTR to RTL.

I need to be able to set a specific Cell or better yet, a column, to be RTL.

Please note that I'm not talking about the alignment of the cell, I'm talking about the text direction.

this is not a duplication of [Set direction sheet in PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154903/set-direction-sheet-in-phpexcel)

thanks

Comment: Marked as duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154903/set-direction-sheet-in-phpexcel

Comment: whoever marked this as duplicate did not understand the question. This is not the same as the other question. The code bellow shows how to make a single cell RTL with PHP Excel.

Answer (score 3):

This can only be set at the Worksheet level using

```
// right-to-left worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setRightToLeft(true);
```

not for individual cells, ranges of cells, columns or rows

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer to this by a dear friend (Bastien Koert) :

```
This takes care of the RTL for a single Cell.
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J' , $i)->getAlignment()->setReadorder(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::READORDER_RTL);

This takes care of the right alignment needed with Hebrew
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J' , $i)->getAlignment()-  >setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
```

Comment: Thanks, `PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::READORDER_RTL` worked for me. We can use it for single or range of cell.