# How to set the direction of a cell comment (to RTL) with PHP Excel?

Tags: php, excel, right-to-left

I need to change the direction of a comment in a single cell or better yet, make all comments in a sheet RTL. I can do this for the cell it self but could not manage for the comment.

This can be done manually in Excel but i want to do it via PHP Excel.

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422237/php-excel-set-cell-or-column-direction-rtl

Comment: The above is how to make the contents of a cell RTL, not a cell's comment.