# How to set text direction in cells in PHPExcel?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have to write texts in cells that are combinations of RTL and LTR languages inline and the prior language is the RTL one. So I need the text in xls file generated by PHPExcel to be RTL by default. What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set direction sheet in PHPExcel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154903/set-direction-sheet-in-phpexcel)

Comment: Thank you, but that question is about sheet direction not text direction.

Answer (score 4):

To set direction for the entire worksheet, you can use:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setRightToLeft(true);
```

For an individual cell (or range of cells) you can try:

```
// Set the character order as RTL
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1')
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setReadorder(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::READORDER_RTL);
// Set cell alignment to the right
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1')
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
```

Comment: Thanks, `PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::READORDER_RTL` worked for me.